# Karate SAXParseException when logPrettyResponse is true and response content type is 'text/turtle'

Tags: karate

It looks like a bug but asking the question just in case I have missed something.

Karate version is 1.1.0

The post request is as below. Note that content type is text/turtle and I use logPrettyResponse because further requests in test are testing RDF/XML and other serialisations.

```
    * configure logPrettyResponse = true

    Given path '/graph'
    * text payload =
      """
        <http://example.com/a7460f22-561a-4dde-922b-665bd9cf3bd9> <http://schema.org/description> "Test"@en.
      """
    And request payload
    And header Accept = 'text/turtle'
    And header Content-Type = 'text/turtle'
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

And I get below error

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 8; Element type "http:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"., http call failed
```

Reason this seems to be happening is that `fromString` method in JsValue.java is trying to parse turtle as XML because condition `case '<'` is true when response is turtle.

```
   public static Object fromString(String raw, boolean jsonStrict, ResourceType resourceType) {
        String trimmed = raw.trim();
        if (trimmed.isEmpty()) {
            return raw;
        }
        if (resourceType != null && resourceType.isBinary()) {
            return raw;
        }
        switch (trimmed.charAt(0)) {
            case '{':
            case '[':
                return jsonStrict ? JsonUtils.fromJsonStrict(raw) : JsonUtils.fromJson(raw);
            case '<':
                if (resourceType == null || resourceType.isXml()) {
                    return XmlUtils.toXmlDoc(raw);
                } else {
                    return raw;
                }
            default:
                return raw;
        }
    }
```

To solve the problem I have set logPrettyResponse to false. I would love to know if anyone has any other thoughts or if someone can confirm that it is a bug?

Comment: not sure, asking someone to look at this. will try and respond in a day or two

Comment: There were some recent improvements in this area (due to appear in v1.2.0) to make body handling more aware of the content type defined in the HTTP headers. I revisited those changes and realised that pretty logging was not yet picking up the content type so I just created a PR to fix it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/pull/1932. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @PeteEdwards great.